# Отдача изображений нужного размера

Tags: изображения

В некоторый сайтах в ссылке на изображение присутствуют параметры размера ( ширина, высота), и в зависимости от значения параметра сервер отдаёт изображение нужного размера.
 Как это можно реализовать?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял, у Вас имеется хранилище с оригинальными изображениями.
Я бы сделал небольшое отдельное Web-приложение, которое будет обрабатывать запросы за изображениями. Смысл работы приложения в следующем:

- если размер изображения не указан - отдаём оригинальное изображение
- если размер указан, возможны 2 случая: размер больше оригинального - отдаём оригинальное изображение; размер меньше оригинального - ресайзим изображение любыми нужными Вам средствами и отдаём его в HTTP-Response.

***Возможные улучшения:***

- Чтобы при каждом обращении к изображению с указанными размерами не выполнять ресайзинг, логично было бы сохранять изображение на сервере после первого ресайзинга, а при последующих обращениях отдавать уже его.
- При ответе выставляйте нужные HTTP-заголовки, чтобы также закэшировать изображения в браузерах.

Также я бы ввёл ограничение на размеры, то есть ресайзил изображение только в том случае, если указанные высота и ширина попадают в список "разрешённых" размеров.

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли. Но есть ли уже готовое решение для PHP? В целом алгоритм понял, думаю всё получиться. Но тут возник вопрос: а есть ли смысл так делать если мне надо 2-3 изображения разных размеров. Сильно ли увеличится нагрузка на сервер?

Comment: @Idaho371 
Я бы назвал реализацию crop-функционала базовым, потому не стоит даже ставить такой вопрос. Кроме того, Вам указали на то, что после первого прохождения подготовленные изображения необходимо закэшировать, и в случая повторного запроса, оные будут браться уже из кэша.

Answer (score 3):

Вы наверно имеете в виду crop-библиотеку [timthumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/demo/timthumb-basic/)

Но мне, если честно, такая реализация не нравится (динамический uri, где в get-параметрах(аргументах) указан размер изображения и не только), лучше что-то вроде такого решения: [kama-thumbnail](http://wp-kama.ru/id_142/kama-thumbnail.html). Данная реализация чем-то похожа на phpThumb в CMF MODx - выдаёт либо src-путь, либо весь тег img с указанными атрибутами. Кэширование прилагается. Минус: говнокод, потому для себя провёл тщательный рефакторинг. Кстати, вот мой форк этого класса: http://ideone.com/9yrBZz

Листинг по форку:

```
$this->image = new Thumb;

/**
 * Возвращает тег img
 *
 *  src – ссылка на оригинал изображения, которую нужно уменьшить (обязателен)
    w – ширина миниатюры (обязательный)
    h – высота миниатюры (обязательный)
    q – качество сжатия jpg (по умолчанию 85. макс.100)
    alt – атрибут alt
    class – атрибут class
    no_attr - если не требуется выводить для изображения атрибуты height и width
    no_stub - если не требуется выводить изображение-заглушку, если оное отсутствует
 */
$this->image->getImg('
    src=/img/image_1.jpg
    &w=140
    &h=119
    &alt=картинка'
);

/**
 * Возвращает src
 */
$this->image->getSrc('...');
```

Либо написать свое решение с нуля. Рекомендую использовать PECL-extension Imagick - там есть где разгуляться.

Comment: @Idaho371 Добавил ссылку на свой форк с мануалом.

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$height = 240;
$width= 320;
?>
<img src="URL" height="<? echo $height;?>" width="<?echo $width; ?>"  />
```

Это ведь основы html

Comment: Нет, Вы не поняли. Это к HTML никак не относится. Это происходит на стороне сервера. Ведь это происходит при вводе прямой ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что изображения выводятся в определенный блок/блоки, а в CSS, для всех дочерних изображений этих блоков, прописано правило. Например, так:

```
#some_block img {
   max-width: 150px;
   max-height: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовый класс, который позволяет изменять размеры изображения и сохранять в файл либо изменять размеры и выдавать картинку

```
class picture {

    private $image_file;

    public $image;
    public $image_type;
    public $image_width;
    public $image_height;

    public function __construct($image_file) {
        $this->image_file=$image_file;
        $image_info = getimagesize($this->image_file);
        $this->image_width = $image_info[0];
        $this->image_height = $image_info[1];
        switch($image_info[2]) {
            case 1: $this->image_type = 'gif'; break;//1: IMAGETYPE_GIF
            case 2: $this->image_type = 'jpeg'; break;//2: IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            case 3: $this->image_type = 'png'; break;//3: IMAGETYPE_PNG
            case 4: $this->image_type = 'swf'; break;//4: IMAGETYPE_SWF
            case 5: $this->image_type = 'psd'; break;//5: IMAGETYPE_PSD
            case 6: $this->image_type = 'bmp'; break;//6: IMAGETYPE_BMP
            case 7: $this->image_type = 'tiffi'; break;//7: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (порядок байт intel)
            case 8: $this->image_type = 'tiffm'; break;//8: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (порядок байт motorola)
            case 9: $this->image_type = 'jpc'; break;//9: IMAGETYPE_JPC
            case 10: $this->image_type = 'jp2'; break;//10: IMAGETYPE_JP2
            case 11: $this->image_type = 'jpx'; break;//11: IMAGETYPE_JPX
            case 12: $this->image_type = 'jb2'; break;//12: IMAGETYPE_JB2
            case 13: $this->image_type = 'swc'; break;//13: IMAGETYPE_SWC
            case 14: $this->image_type = 'iff'; break;//14: IMAGETYPE_IFF
            case 15: $this->image_type = 'wbmp'; break;//15: IMAGETYPE_WBMP
            case 16: $this->image_type = 'xbm'; break;//16: IMAGETYPE_XBM
            case 17: $this->image_type = 'ico'; break;//17: IMAGETYPE_ICO
            default: $this->image_type = ''; break;
        }
        $this->fotoimage();
    }

    private function fotoimage() {
        switch($this->image_type) {
            case 'gif': $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($this->image_file); break;
            case 'jpeg': $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->image_file); break;
            case 'png': $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($this->image_file); break;
        }
    }

    public function autoimageresize($new_w, $new_h) {
        $difference_w = 0;
        $difference_h = 0;
        if($this->image_width < $new_w && $this->image_height < $new_h) {
            $this->imageresize($this->image_width, $this->image_height);
        }
        else {
            if($this->image_width > $new_w) {
                $difference_w = $this->image_width - $new_w;
            }
            if($this->image_height > $new_h) {
                $difference_h = $this->image_height - $new_h;
            }
                if($difference_w > $difference_h) {
                    $this->imageresizewidth($new_w);
                }
                elseif($difference_w < $difference_h) {
                    $this->imageresizeheight($new_h);
                }
                else {
                    $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
                }
        }
    }

    public function percentimagereduce($percent) {
        $new_w = round($this->image_width * $percent / 100);
        $new_h = round($this->image_height * $percent / 100);
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresizewidth($new_w) {
        $new_h = round($this->image_height * ($new_w / $this->image_width));
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresizeheight($new_h) {
        $new_w = round($this->image_width * ($new_h / $this->image_height));
        $this->imageresize($new_w, $new_h);
    }

    public function imageresize($new_w, $new_h) {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $this->image_width, $this->image_height);
        $this->image_width = $new_w;
        $this->image_height = $new_h;
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    public function imagesave($image_type='jpeg', $image_file=NULL, $image_compress=100, $image_permiss='') {
        if($image_file==NULL) {
            switch($this->image_type) {
                case 'gif': header("Content-type: image/gif"); break;
                case 'jpeg': header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); break;
                case 'png': header("Content-type: image/png"); break;
            }
        }
        switch($this->image_type) {
            case 'gif': imagegif($this->image, $image_file); break;
            case 'jpeg': imagejpeg($this->image, $image_file, $image_compress); break;
            case 'png': imagepng($this->image, $image_file); break;
        }
        if($image_permiss != '') {
            chmod($image_file, $image_permiss);
        }
    }

    public function imageout() {
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

}
```